# Tikz overlay for subfigure environment- beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, subfloats, overlays

I have been trying to create a list and a bunch of subfigures (both on each half of the slide). I have used `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`to progress along the list per keystroke. I want this keystroke to also be used to draw tikz overlays on the figure. I saw quite a few solutions, but all of them were using just a single figure. I cant seem to get it working for subfigures. Can someone please help me out..

Here is my minimal code..

```
\frame  
{  
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}  
\frametitle{Title}  
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}  
\begin{itemize}[<+->]  
\item  
\item  
\item  
\item  
\end{itemize}  
\end{minipage}  
\hfill   
\vspace{-120pt}  
\begin{minipage}[t]{2\linewidth}  
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}  
\begin{figure}[!th]  
\centering  
\subfigure[1]{  
\includegraphics[scale=.25]{scen-q.pdf}  
\label{fig:scen1subfig1}  
}  
\hspace{-10pt}  
\subfigure[2]{  
\includegraphics[scale=.25]{scen-b.pdf}  
\label{fig:scen1subfig2}  
}
\newline
\subfigure[3]{
\includegraphics[scale=.25]{scen-s.pdf}
\label{fig:scen1subfig3}
}  
\subfigure[4]{  
\includegraphics[scale=.25]{scen-sw.pdf}  
\label{fig:scen1subfig4}  
}  
\hspace{130pt}  
\label{fig:scencomp}  
\end{figure}  
\end{minipage}  
}
```

I have seen this as a solution before

```
\begin{tikzpicture}    
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1\textheight]{5.pdf}};  
\draw<1>[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (1.6,1) rectangle (\textheight-1cm,5);  
\draw<2>[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (5.7,4.1) rectangle (7.5,4.9);  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But how do I do the same for subfigures?

Comment: Can you complete your code snippet to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem and shows which packages you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the kind of overlay effect that you are trying to achieve; I used `\onslide` so that each image will become visible simultaneously with a corresponding item:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}  
\frametitle{Title}  

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}  
\begin{itemize}[<+->]  
\item  First item.
\item  Second item.
\item  Third item.
\item  Fourth item.
\end{itemize}  
\end{minipage}%  
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}  
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}  
\begin{figure} 
\onslide<1->{\subfigure[1]{%  
  \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{scen-q.pdf}
}%
\label{fig:scen1subfig1}}\hfill
\onslide<2->{\subfigure[2]{% 
  \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{scen-b.pdf}  
}%
\label{fig:scen1subfig2}}\\
\onslide<3->{\subfigure[3]{%
  \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{scen-s.pdf}
}%  
\label{fig:scen1subfig3}}\hfill
\onslide<4>{\subfigure[4]{%  
  \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{scen-sw.pdf}  
}%
\label{fig:scen1subfig4}}%
\caption{test figure}
\label{fig:scencomp}  
\end{figure}  
\end{minipage}  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please notice that I included some `%` characters that are essential to suppress spurious blank spaces. Also, `subfigure` is an obsolete package, so it would be a good idea to use [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) instead.

Since I didn't have your actual figures, I used `\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}`; this simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; delete that line in your actual document.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your response..I will try it out immediately!

Comment: Hi, as a more elegant way to solve my problem,  I came across `\fcolorbox`. With this I can draw boxes on top of my figures and highlight what I wanna speak about, but I am now restricted by the size of this box. Is there a way to draw a box to any size without putting text into it?

Comment: @jamie sure, but it's hard to give precise advise without seeing some code illustrating what are you trying to do. Can you please edit your question and add (not replace, just add) the new information and a minimal example (as in my answer) of your code?